# Differentiability of $f$ if $f = \sum f_k$ and $f_k$ are differentiable at one point

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function, where $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is open. Suppose there exist functions $f_k:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n,$ $k\in\mathbb{N}$, such that for all $x\in U$:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x).$$

Moreover, suppose that each $f_k$ is differentiable at some point $x_0\in U$. Does this imply that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$?

Unfortunately, I do not know the answer. I checked some examples, and it seems to be correct. I would be thankful, if someone can help me.

Comment: I would look up uniform convergence in a real analysis textbook, it should exactly answer your question.

Comment: Indeed $f$ might not even be continuous.

Comment: We have the following theorem that's often useful: if a series $\sum f_k(x_0)$ converges at some point $x_0\in [a,b]$ and the series of derivatives $g(x) = \sum f_k'(x)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ then the series $f(x) = \sum f_k(x)$ converges uniformly for all $x\in[a,b]$ and $f(x)$ is differentiable with $f'(x) = g(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} F_n(x),$$
for $F_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x)$.

So if we set $f_{n+1}=h_{n+1}-F_n$ for some differenitable function $h_{n+1}$, then $F_{n+1}=F_n+f_{n+1}=h_{n+1}$.
Thus the question reduces to showing that a limit of diffenretiable functions is differentiable.

The answer is no!
Its not hard to come up with an example. Take your favorite function which is not differentiable at $0$ (e.g. |x|) and try to approximate it by differentiable functions.

Can you do that?

Answer (score 3):

Wrong. E.g. the non-continuous square wave has a Fourier series by sine functions only, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series

--- rk